# how to get previous matching value

Tags: r, dataframe

how to get value of "a" if value of b matches with most recent previous value e.g - row$3 of b matches with previous row$1 ,row$6 matches with row$4

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2013,2013,2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016),
           a = c(10,11,NA,13,22,NA,19,NA,10,15,NA),
           b = c(30.133,29,30.1223,33,17,33,11,17,14,13.913,14))

  year  a   b   *NEW*
2013    10  30.133  NA
2013    11  29      NA
2014    NA  30.1223 10
2014    13  33      NA
2014    22  17      NA
2015    NA  33      13
2015    19  11      NA
2015    NA  17      22
2016    10  14      NA
2016    15  13.913  10
2016    NA  14      15
```

Thanks

Comment: @SrmMurty when the values `30.133` and `30.1223` are rounded to two decimals, they are not equal. So, there will be no matching value. Do you have a different requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For OPs example case

One way could be is to use `duplicated()` function.

```
# Input dataframe    
df <- data.frame(year = c(2013,2013,2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016),
                     a = c(10,11,NA,13,22,NA,19,NA,10,15,NA),
                     b = c(30,29,30,33,17,33,11,17,14,14,14))

# creating a new column with default values
df$NEW <- NA

# updating the value using the previous matching position
df$NEW[duplicated(df$b)] <- df$a[duplicated(df$b,fromLast = TRUE)]

# expected output
df
#    year  a  b NEW
# 1  2013 10 30  NA
# 2  2013 11 29  NA
# 3  2014 NA 30  10
# 4  2014 13 33  NA
# 5  2014 22 17  NA
# 6  2015 NA 33  13
# 7  2015 19 11  NA
# 8  2015 NA 17  22
# 9  2016 10 14  NA
# 10 2016 15 14  10
# 11 2016 NA 14  15
```

#### General purpose usage

The above solution fails when the duplicates are not in sequential order. As per @DavidArenburg's advice. I have changed the fourth element `df$b[4] <- 14`. The general solution would require the usage of another handy function `order()` and should work for different possible cases.

```
# Input dataframe    
df <- data.frame(year = c(2013,2013,2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016),
                 a = c(10,11,NA,13,22,NA,19,NA,10,15,NA),
                 b = c(30,29,30,14,17,33,11,17,14,14,14))

# creating a new column with default values
df$NEW <- NA

# sort the matching column
df <- df[order(df$b),]

# updating the value using the previous matching position
df$NEW[duplicated(df$b)] <- df$a[duplicated(df$b,fromLast = TRUE)]

# To original order
df <- df[order(as.integer(rownames(df))),]

# expected output
df
#    year  a  b NEW
# 1  2013 10 30  NA
# 2  2013 11 29  NA
# 3  2014 NA 30  10
# 4  2014 13 14  NA
# 5  2014 22 17  NA
# 6  2015 NA 33  NA
# 7  2015 19 11  NA
# 8  2015 NA 17  22
# 9  2016 10 14  13
# 10 2016 15 14  10
# 11 2016 NA 14  15
```

Here, the solution is based on the `base` package' functions. I am sure there should other ways of doing this using other packages.

Comment: Thanks Prradep , can we add round function with 2 decimal if the exact value is not available

Comment: Please update the expected output in the question and I would try the possibilities.

Comment: Question edidted Prradep

Comment: You can use `round(df$b, 3)` before using the above statements.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I could not figure out how it would be an issue as the output is based on the previous matching instance.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, it works with OPs example and fails in general cases.